# Google Colab: cannot install cudf

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, rapids, cudf

I need help. I am using Google Colab with Python 3.10.11 and I have a Colab with CUDA Version: 12.0 , Nvidia driver version 525.85.12 and I am following this tutorial on how to install cuDF  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TAAi_szMfWqRfHVfjGSqnGVLr_ztzUM9#scrollTo=G_2dancFhf70

I checked
`nvidia-smi`

and I have been allocated Tesla T4

On the step   
`!python rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/install_rapids.py stable`  
`import os`    
`os.environ\['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'\] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so'`     
`os.environ\['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'\] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice/'`    
 `os.environ\['CONDA_PREFIX'\] = '/usr/local'`
`!pip uninstall cupy -y`

I am getting the following warning:  
`WARNING conda.core.solve:\_add_specs(639): pinned spec python=3.10 conflicts with explicit   specs.  Overriding pinned spec.` 
`WARNING conda.core.solve:\_add_specs(639): pinned spec cudatoolkit=11.8 conflicts with explicit  specs.  Overriding pinned spec.`

`SpecsConfigurationConflictError: Requested specs conflict with configured specs.` 
`requested specs:`
 `- cudatoolkit=11.2` 
 `- dask-sql` 
 `- gcsfs` 
`- llvmlite` 
`- mamba==1.4.1` 
`- openssl` 
`- python=3.9` 
`- rapids=22.12` 
`pinned specs:` 
`- python_abi=3.10[build=*cp310*]` 
`Use 'conda config --show-sources' to look for 'pinned_specs' and 'track_features'` 
 `configuration parameters.  Pinned specs may also be defined in the file` 
 `/usr/local/conda-meta/pinned.`

and when I am proceeding with the next step: 
`import cudf`

I receive an error:  
`No module named 'cudf'`

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: on top on nick's suggestion, i've updated RAPIDS version to current latest as this colab env supports latest RAPIDS via conda install: https://github.com/rapidsai-community/rapidsai-csp-utils/pull/79

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the preferred way to install RAPIDS frameworks on Colab is to use pip. If you use the "Launch Google Colab (Pip)" link at [rapids.ai/#quick-start](https://rapids.ai/#quick-start) (or directly run the code in the notebook generated from that link, which I've listed below), things should work for you.

```
# This get the RAPIDS-Colab install files and test check your GPU.  Run this and the next cell only.
# Please read the output of this cell.  If your Colab Instance is not RAPIDS compatible, it will warn you and give you remediation steps.
!git clone https://github.com/rapidsai/rapidsai-csp-utils.git
!python rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/pip-install.py
```

Answer (score 1):

try out
`!pip install --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com cudf-cu11`.
you can even pin versions using `cuml-cu11==23.06.00` etc

whole process takes just 2-3min, much improved!